# how to split the array and store into the database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I split this array and store into the database?

I have three fields in my model called `Question_id, Answer_id and Phase_id`.

I have a result like:

```
question_hash_string = "{\"5\":[\"5\",\"0\",\"\"],\"25\":[\"25\",\"1\",\"3\"]}"}
```

Which looks like `{5:[5,0,1], 25:[25,1,3] ... }`.

I want to split the array and store the results into the three fields in order `Question`, `Answer` and `Phase` of each set.

In my `Batch` table, I have three columns: `question_id`, `answer_id` and `phase_id`.

The first value of `array[5,0,1]`, `5` goes to `question_id`, `0` to `answer_id` and `1` to `phase_id`. In the second row `25` to `question_id`, `1` to `answer_id` and `3` to `phase_id`.

Comment: How do you want to store I mean all are in same table??

Comment: @checkit Yes, If i have a table called Batch and three columns like Question, answer and phase. I want to store first value to question, second to answer and third to phase of each array list in row by row in the database...

Comment: is key indicates batch id??

Comment: key indicates the question_id.. but the question_id is also inside the array. so if we need, we can take the key otherwise take it from the arraylist.

Comment: i have answered it. did u check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
hash_values = JSON.parse(question_hash_string)
hash_values.each do |k,v|
  b = Batch.new
  b.question_id, b.answer_id, b.phase_id = v.collect(&:to_i)
  b.save!
end
```

Comment: sometimes the answer would come in a string? is it possible to do the same for a string inside the array?

Comment: string means, can you give an example?

Comment: for example, {5:[5,Name,1], 25[25,1,3] and so on }

Comment: Please clarify of Whats the k for in the hash_values.each do?

Comment: k is the key. let assume {1:[2,3,4]} here k is 1 and v is [2,3,4]

Comment: You told you have three models. And you want to store id's of each in Batch table, right? then what does 5:[5,name,1] mean??

Comment: hi, Not three models... Just single model called Batch, three columns(fields) like Question, Answer and phase..

Comment: ok then you just use v instead of v.collect(&:to_i). 25[25,1,3] is 25:[25,1,3] right?

Comment: yes. so if i use just v should save the datas from 25[25, false, 3]?

Comment: What is your Batch model columns types?? You told that it has fields for question_id, answer_id and phase_id.

Comment: the answer_id type is char(30)

Comment: If you use v instead of v.collect(&:to_i) v looks like ["25", "false", "3"] so if you have all fields as char(30) it will store values as string. Ruby is dynamically typed not your SQL(mysql, sqlite, whatever you using). But your column names are not semantically correct.

Comment: I guess using v does not collect the values like v.collect(&.to_i)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22773/discussion-between-vinay-and-checkit)

Comment: Here v is array and v.collect(&:to_i) is used to convert elements into integer. And v.collect(&:to_i) finally returns array but with integer values. But u told it can be string so just v is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to parse this with JSON:

```
json_loaded = JSON.load(question_hash_string)
```

From there you can emit in any format you might wish, but will need to convert your values to integers:

```
remapped = Hash[
  json_loaded.collect do |k, a|
    [ k.to_i, a.collect(&:to_i) ]
  end
]
# => {5=>[5, 0, 0], 25=>[25, 1, 3]}

JSON.dump(remapped)
# => {"5":[5,0,0],"25":[25,1,3]}
```

Since JSON requires string keys, this is very close to what you want. To get it precisely the same you'd have to write a custom emitter.

Comment: Thank you ... am a newbie.. so will you tell me how to select the first value of the first array?  I don't have an idea of custom emitter...

Comment: @Vinay : `remapped.first` will return the first key value pair `["5", [1, 2, 3]]` as an array